# How can I move an unpublished iOS app to an another account with the same name?

Tags: ios, itunes, connect, rules

I developed an app up to about 30-40%. I registered it on my personal App Store Account. I want to move the unpublished app to a new, enterprise App Store Account(it's very important for me to keep the same name). I tought of deleting it from my account and creating it on the enterprise account but I'm afraid something won't work. I wish to do this without publishing the app or as easy as possible. Is there any solution to my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can delete from your account and after successful deletion, create new app on enterprise account. Don't need afraid on it.

Comment: also, you need to remove the AppId from your Personal Account before creating a certificat with the same AppId on the Enterprise one.

Answer (score 1):

**No, Without publishing the app you can not transfer the app to another account because of Apple Guideline.**

```
App must be in a transferable state. You can transfer your app when it is one 
of the following states.
Ready for Sale
Pending Contract
Prepare for Upload
Developer Removed from Sale
Invalid Binary
Developer Rejected
Rejected
```

Also there is  need to delete the app from first account if you do not want. Just create the same app with that information to second account. It will not affect because your app is not live from your first account.